# Java LocalDateTime Text could not be parsed at index 0 exception

Tags: java, localdatetime

Trying to convert a date which is in String format to Java LocalDateTime.

```
private DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
private String caseStartDate = dateFormat.format(LocalDateTime.now());

LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(caseStartDate);
```

But ends up having this exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/03/2020 15:13' could not be parsed at index 0

Doesnt this format support for conversion?

Comment: "Doesnt this format support for conversion?" Who told you it does? `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` internally. Do you mean to write `parse(caseStartDate, dateFormat)`?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain? And why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use your format inside [LocalDateTime::parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        String caseStartDate = dateFormat.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(caseStartDate);
        LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(caseStartDate, dateFormat);
        System.out.println(localdatetime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
01/05/2020 09:13
2020-05-01T09:13
```

Also, see how the `toString()` method of `LocalDateTime` has been overridden:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString();
}
```